# Laravel 8 deployed on Ubuntu but keep getting: Undefined variable

Tags: laravel, windows, ubuntu, deployment

I have build a project on a windows 10 machine and now that it is allmost finshed I tried to deploy it on a ubuntu 20.04.2 server on a virtual machine. But now that I've got it working I keep getting Undefined variable errors (see below).

[image]

I can't seem to find anything about this so I'm thinking it has to do with the differences between the windows file structure an the linux file structure. Could somebody confirm or deny that. And if so give me a possible solution?

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: does removing the `$back` variable from your view file solve the problem?

Comment: nope nothing related to file structure or file permissions

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not Windows/Linux related.

The `$back` variable is not being sent to the View. Please check the Controller that loads the view called: `config-menu.blade.php` . You can also search for `'back'` or `"back"` and see where this variable is defined/sent from (I believe you should search it in the Controller that is calling the View).

The error message also suggests a fix for your problem: Replace: `{{ $back }}` with `{{ $back ?? '' }}` in the `config-menu.blade.php` file. The `??` operator returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL, otherwise it returns its second operand.

Comment: It appears to be a known issue for Laravel 7.x that you cant set a default value in the constructor. You have explicitly give the value.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31980